# Headset mic and speakers not working at same time

Tags: 18.04, sound, microphone, headset

My headset microphone only works when I choose option "Microphone" on Sound Settings, but when I select this options I can hear a "click" in the headset speaker and it stops working.

[image: Sound Settings]

When I change to other input option, speakers works fine again.

Already tried with several headset, even with the simple ones that comes with smartphones, doesn't work either.

My notebook is a Dell Vostro running Ubuntu 18.04

```
head -n 1 /proc/asound/card0/codec*
==> /proc/asound/card0/codec#0 <==
Codec: Realtek ALC3204
```

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xa52a0000 irq 157
```

```
lspci |grep Audio
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9dc8 (rev 30)
```

Comment: Do you know which audio chipset you have? or which machine you are running into this issue on?

Comment: Just edited my question to insert this information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you ever figured this out, but I just ran into the same problem using Pop!_OS 20.10 - basically Ubuntu.

I just killed pulseaudio and restarted it to get stereo sound and mic back. I did it with:

```
$ pulseaudio -k
$ pulseaudio -D
```

My system had another symptom in that my headphones were only playing mono sound. I don't know if that was your experience as well.

I don't know how long this will fix it, but it seems to have worked this time. I found my solution here: https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-pulseaudio-issues-in-linux/